# Как правильней реализовать автопостинг по времени?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite3

Как я планирую:
Сохраняю ид, интервал и время последнего поста в бд (sqlite3)
Потом каждую секунду чекаю бд, и если время подошло, то делаю пост.

Но мне кажется, это не эффективно.

Comment: https://github.com/dbader/schedule

Comment: https://stackabuse.com/scheduling-jobs-with-python-crontab/